# Source for UV cut-off values of buffers

Tags: analytical-chemistry, reference-request, chromatography, databases

When I want to check a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value I look it up in *CRC Handbook*. Is there such source for UV cut-off values of various buffers?

Usually books in chromatography contain tables with that data, but often no source is given.

Comment: Unless you use quartz cells the cut of will be limited by the glass(pyrex ,BK7 etc)/plastic at about 300nm. If there are any aromatics in your sample (and it is not coloured)  the cut off will be in the 250 -400nm region,  every other solution will absorb below about 210nm.

Answer (score 5):

Snyder cites an article by Li [1] as the primary source for UV cutoff values ("Ref 7" below) for various buffers [2, p. 299]:

> **TABLE 7.1 Buffers for Use in HPLC Separation**
>
> $$\begin{array}{lrcr}
> \hline
> \text{Buffer} & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} & \text{Buffer Range}^\textit{a} & \text{UV Cutoff}^\textit{b} \\
> \hline
> \text{Trifluoracetic acid} & \gg 2 & 1.5{–}2.5 & \pu{210 nm}~(0.1\,\%) \\
> \text{Phosphoric acid/mono- or di-K} & 2.1 & <3.1 & <\pu{200 nm}~(0.1\,\%) \\
> \quad\text{phosphate} & 7.2 & 6.2{–}8.2 & \\
>   & 12.3 & 11.3{–}13.3 & <\pu{200 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Citric acid/tri-K citrate} & 3.1 & & \\
>   & 4.7 & 2.1{–}6.4 & \pu{230 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
>   & 5.4 & & \\
> \text{Formic acid/K-formate} & 3.8 & 2.8{–}4.8 & \pu{210 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Acetic acid/K-acetate} & 4.8 & 3.8{–}5.8 & \pu{210 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Mono-/di-K carbonate} & 6.4 & 5.4{–}7.4^\textit{c} & <\pu{200 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
>   & 10.3 & 9.3{–}11.3 & <\pu{200 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Bis-tris propane}^\textit{e}\cdot\ce{HCl}/\text{Bis-tris} & 6.8 & 5.8{–}7.8 & \pu{215 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \quad\text{propane} & 9.0 & 8.0{–}10.0 & \pu{225 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Tris}^\textit{d}\cdot\ce{HCl}/\text{tris} & 8.3 & 7.3{–}9.3 & \pu{205 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Ammonium chloride/ammonia} & 9.2 & 8.2{–}10.2 & \pu{200 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{1-Methylpiperidine}\cdot\ce{HCl}/\text{1-} & & & \\
> \quad\text{Methylpiperidine} & 10.1 & 9.1{–}11.1 & \pu{215 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \text{Triethylamine}\cdot\ce{HCl}/\text{triethylamine} & 11.0 & 10.0{–}12.0 & <\pu{200 nm}~(\pu{10 mM}) \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> $^\textit{a}$ $\mathrm{pH}$ range allowed with this buffer (conservative estimate).
> $^\textit{b}$ Absorbance $<0.5\mathrm{A};$ from Ref. 7.
> $^\textit{c}$ Requires addition of an acid (e.g., acetic or phosphoric).
> $^\textit{d}$ tris(hydroxymethyl)aminomethane.
> $^\textit{e}$ 1,3-bis[Tris(hydroxymethyl)methylamino]propane.

#### References

1. Li, J. B. Signal-to-Noise Optimization in HPLC UV Detection. *LC GC* **1992**, 10 (11), 856–864.
2. Snyder, L. R.; Kirkland, J. J.; Glajch, J. L. *Practical HPLC Method Development*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: New York, **1997**. ISBN 978-0-471-00703-6.